# Add specific column value for first unique value in other column in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to add a column to a data frame based on the values in an other column. I want a specific value for the first  time a value appears in the other column only. For example:

```
 s <- c(6,5,6,7,8,7,6,5)
 i <- c(4,5,4,3,2,3,4,5)
 t <- c(1,1,3,4,5,6,6,8)
 df<- data.frame(t,s,i)
 > df
   t s i
 1 1 6 4
 2 1 5 5
 3 3 6 4
 4 4 7 3
 5 5 8 2
 6 6 7 3
 7 6 6 4
 8 8 5 5
```

Now I want to add a column "mark" that gives a 1 for the first time t=1 and the first time t=6. So that I get: 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0. I have this code:

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
         if (df$t[i] == 1 & df$t[i-1] != 1 | (df$t[i] == 6 & df$t[i-1] != 6)){
              df$mark[i] <- 1
         } else {
              df$mark[i] <- 0
         }
    }
```

This however gives the following error:

```
     Error in if (df$t[i] == 1 & df$t[i - 1] != 1 | (df$t[i] == 6 & df$t[i -  :argument is of length zero
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use loops, just do

```
df$mark <- 0
df$mark[match(c(1, 6), df$t)] <- 1
```

from `?match` documentation

> match returns a vector of the positions of (**first**) matches of its
>   first argument in its second.

The reason you are getting an error in your loop is because you are looping from 1 to `nrow(df)`. But in your loop you are specifying `df$t[i-1]`, which basically means `df$t[0]` in your first iteration; which is a non-existing entry

Comment: Wow, this is so simple, thanks! I'd never heard of match before.

Answer (score 0):

```
  within(df, mark<- (c(1,diff(t %in% c(1,6)))==1) +0)
   #     t s i mark
   #   1 1 6 4    1
   #   2 1 5 5    0
   #   3 3 6 4    0
   #   4 4 7 3    0
   #   5 5 8 2    0
   #   6 6 7 3    1
   #   7 6 6 4    0
   #   8 8 5 5    0
```

Or

```
  duplicated(df$t,fromLast=T) +0
  #[1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```